Axon v4.9.5 startup problem, came out of nowhere
I've built my CQRS project Core-API, where i have declared events, and commands, also the AxonConfig (just some xStream allowtypesByWildcard)
Till this point, everythings works fine
I created the CommandService,
i added this dependency
`        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.axonframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>axon-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>4.9.2</version>
        </dependency>`


Along with other dependencies like eureka, openFeign and loadbalancer
Whenever i start the project i get these warnings:
`
WARN 6976 --- [ms-command-products] [main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'springAxonConfiguration
`

`
    WARN 6976 --- [ms-command-products] [nfoReplicator-0] c.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient                : Request execution failed with message: I/O error on POST request for    
 "http://localhost:8888/eureka/apps/MS-COMMAND-PRODUCTS": Socket closed
`


`
    WARN 6976 --- [ms-command-products] [nfoReplicator-0] c.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient        : Request execution failed with message: Connection pool shut down
    2024-05-13T15:41:43.054+01:00  WARN 6976 --- [ms-command-products] [nfoReplicator-0]     com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_MS-COMMAND-PRODUCTS/localhost:ms-    command-products:8083 - registration failed Cannot execute request on any known server
`

`
    WARN 6976 --- [ms-command-products] [nfoReplicator-0] c.n.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator     : There was a problem with the instance info replicator
`

`
    WARN 6976 --- [ms-command-products] [           main] c.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient    : Request execution failed with message: Connection pool shut down
    ERROR 6976 --- [ms-command-products] [main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_MS-COMMAND-PRODUCTS/localhost:ms-command-products:8083 - de-registration failedCannot execute request on any known server
`

`
    ERROR 6976 --- [ms-command-products] [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   
`

Then i get this message:
APPLICATION FAILED TO START

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:
    io.grpc.Metadata$Key.validateName(Metadata.java:754)


The following method did not exist:
    'void com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(boolean, java.lang.String, char, java.lang.Object)'

The calling method's class, io.grpc.Metadata$Key, was loaded from the following location:
    jar:file:/C:/Users/medou/.m2/repository/io/grpc/grpc-api/1.59.1/grpc-api-1.59.1.jar!/io/grpc/Metadata$Key.class


The called method's class, com.google.common.base.Preconditions, is available from the following locations:
    jar:file:/C:/Users/medou/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/19.0/guava-19.0.jar!/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.class


The called method's class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:
    com.google.common.base.Preconditions: file:/C:/Users/medou/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/19.0/guava-19.0.jar



Action:
Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes io.grpc.Metadata$Key and com.google.common.base.Preconditions
Process finished with exit code 1
I've been stuck with this for more than a day, what am i missing??

It might be you need grpc-api 1.62.1, at least that works with 4.9.2. Please note that 4.9.3 is the latest version. If you don't need Axon Server (and thus no gRPC communication to Axon Server, you can also set axon.axonserver.enabled=false and it should start regardless of the gRPC problem.

You were right, changing the grpc-api worked, i used this :
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
    <artifactId>grpc-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.59.1</version>
</dependency>

